# Ionic framework : Parse xml from responseText

Tags: javascript, xml, ionic-framework

I get some xml rows from a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object using Javascript. As a result, I get a string from responseText attribute. How do I manage to get information from this string?

```
<items>
    <item info="value" info="otherValue" />
    <item info="value" info="otherValue" />
    <item info="value" info="otherValue" />
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get rid of my trouble by getting my xml content with [ajax from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).